# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the following error when attempting to match values on database with those passed in a form to check if a user exists.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be
>   converted to string

This is the code I'm using:

```
//Check users login details
    function match_login($username, $password){
            //If the button has been clicked get the variables
            try{

                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");

            } catch( PDOException $e ) {

                echo $e->getMessage();

            }
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = mysql_query($stmt);
            if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

                echo 'There is a match!';
            }else{
                echo 'nooooo';
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are not supposed to use `mysql_*` if you are using PDO........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysql_query()` and PDO are not compatible and cannot be used together. You're attempting to pass the PDO statement object to `mysql_query()` which expects a string. Instead, you want to fetch rows from `$stmt` via one of PDO's fetching methods, or check the number of rows returned with [`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password);

if ($stmt->execute()) {

  // get the rowcount
  $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();
  if ($numrows > 0) {
    // match
    // Fetch rows
    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
  else {
    // no rows
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks why did you place the execute method inside an if statement?

Comment: @crm If it fails for some reason it will return FALSE, so just a simple error check.  I suppose in this case it would throw an exception if the execute() failed, so you don't really need to wrap it in an if. You might put it inside a try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and PHP5/PDO don't work well with returning the number of rows. After your new PDO(), issue:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS, true);
```

Then issues your query...

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
$stmt->execute();

// number of rows returned
if($stmt->rowCount()){
    // ... matches
}else{
    // .. no match
}
```

Otherwise your rowCount would be either bool 0, or null/throw error.